# Computing the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (3^nx)}{2^n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (3^nx)}{2^n} $ is convergent for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ by comparison  test $\sum\frac{1}{2^n} $ is converges . **Can I compute the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (3^nx)}{2^n} $**

Comment: Can you compute it?  No.  Can anyone compute it? I assume not.

Comment: Finding a closed form for the partial sum would probably be best way if you want to find it exactly... however, as the answer below suggests, this looks pretty difficult to do (if possible).

Comment: When $\frac{x}{2\pi}$ is rational, $\cos(3^n x)$ will be ultimately periodic in $n$. You can split your series into finitely many geometric series. As a result, the sum can be expressed as a finite linear combination of $\cos(3^nx)$ with rational coefficients. For general $x$, I doubt there is any closed form for the sum.

Comment: This sum looks very similar to a [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) - a continuous function that isn't differentiable at any point.

Comment: @Winther I wonder what impact the condition $ab>1+\frac32\pi$ plays on whether or not a function is a Weierstrass function or not.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That is just a requirement to make Weierstrass original proof go through. One can show that it holds for all sums on the form $\sum a^n \cos(b^n x)$ with $0 < a < 1$ and $ab \geq 1$. This is shown in G. H. Hardy ["Weierstrass's Non-Differentiable Function"](http://perso-math.univ-mlv.fr/users/jaffard.stephane/pdf/Hardy.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the first few partial sums, you can seriously doubt it.

[image]

This "function" is fractal.